# Is there another symbol that is slightly different from \forall (likewise for \exists)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, amssymb

### What

Is there a symbol that is slightly different from `$\forall$` (e.g. having a second line from upper left to lower middle)? It should obviously mean "for all" but be sufficiently different to not be mistaken for `$\forall$`.

Similarly, is there a slightly different symbol than `$\exists$` (e.g. with two lines downward)?

### Why

I need two different symbols to differentiate whether I'm in some formal logic or on the meta level (talking about the logic). Currently I use "f.a." and "ex.", but I think it's easier to grasp complex descriptions if quantifiers stand out.

### Where

I looked in amssymb and http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/symbols/welcome.html, but didn't find a suitable symbol.

Comment: Did you try the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)?

Comment: @Count Zero: Thanks for the comprehensive list. I only found \fgeA from the fge package, and it does not look as good as the answers below (and \fgeE does not exist).

Comment: have these variant symbols been used in published journal articles or books?  if so, they may be candidates to be considered for inclusion in unicode.  citations would be needed; i am the contact person for such material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example defines `\eexists` and `\fforall` with the additional lines as requested in the question.

- `\eexists`: The symbol `\eexists` is composed of `\exists` and the vertical line `|`
  to get a line with a matching line thickness. The vertical line is scaled to the right
  height. This vertical scaling does not change the horizontal line width. Finally the line is moved to the right position.
- `\fforall`: The trick with the vertical line cannot be uses, because the angle is
  not known exactly. Also the angle depends on the font size. The angle can be estimated from the width and height of the symbol.
  For this symbol `TikZ` is used and the line width is guessed from the width of `\forall`.

**Update:**

- Decreased distance between the two lines.
- I have removed the case for `\scriptscriptstyle`, because the symbols have larger
  side bearings that would need to be compensated. But probably the symbols are not needed at such sizes anyway.
- Of course, the "magic numbers" depend on the used font. A different font might need different settings.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\eexists}{%
  {\mathpalette\eexistsAux{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\eexistsAux}[2]{%
  \exists
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\exists$}%
  \sbox2{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1|$}}%
  \kern-.5\wd2 %
  \resizebox{\width}{\ht0}{\copy2}%
  \kern-.25\wd2 %
}
\newcommand*{\fforall}{%
  {\mathpalette\fforallAux{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\fforallAuxx}[1]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\forall$}%
  \sbox2{%
    \rlap{%
      \raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\backslash$}%
    }%
    \kern\ht0 %
  }%
  \sbox2{\resizebox{\ht2}{\height}{\copy2}}%
  \sbox2{\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\copy2}}%
  \wd2=0pt %
  \copy2
  \forall
}
\newsavebox\forallBox
\newdimen\forallLineWidth
\newdimen\forallSep
\newcommand*{\fforallAux}[1]{%
  \sbox\forallBox{$\m@th#1\forall$}%
  \setlength{\forallLineWidth}{.06\wd\forallBox}%
  \setlength{\forallSep}{.09\wd\forallBox}%
  \tikz[
    inner sep=0pt,
    line cap=round,
    line width=\forallLineWidth,
  ]
  \draw
    (0,0) node (A) {\copy\forallBox}
    (A.south) ++(-\forallSep-\forallLineWidth,.4\forallLineWidth)
    coordinate (A1)
    (A.north west) ++(-\forallSep,-\forallLineWidth)
    coordinate (A2)
    (A1) -- (A2)
  ;%
}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \fbox{$\forall$} & \fbox{$\exists$}\\
  \fbox{$\fforall$} & \fbox{$\eexists$}\\
  $\forall^\forall$ & $\exists^\exists$ \\
  $\fforall^\fforall$ & $\eexists^\eexists$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wow, very sophisticated solution (+1). Are you typographically educated and chose the large distance of the separate lines from the original quantifiers on purpose? To me, a little closer looks sweeter...

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 I have updated the answer.

Comment: This is even better than what I was thinking about. Thus this is my (final?) accepted answer.

Comment: Just put it into my text and zoomed all the way in. It's beautiful, man! Thx again.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\myexists}{\ensuremath\exists\kern-.7em\exists}
\newcommand{\myforall}{\kern.05em\ensuremath\forall\kern-.9em\rotatebox{110}{\ensuremath-}}
\newcommand{\myforalll}{\ensuremath\forall\kern-.5em\forall}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\myexists|: $\myexists $ \\
\verb|\myforall|: $\myforall $ \\
\verb|\myforalll|: $\myforalll $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjusting the length of `\myforall`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\myexists}{\ensuremath\exists\kern-.7em\exists}
\newcommand{\myforall}{\kern.05em\ensuremath\forall\kern-.63em\rotatebox{110}{\rule{.73em}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\myforalll}{\ensuremath\forall\kern-.5em\forall}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\myexists|: $\myexists $ \\
\verb|\myforall|: $\myforall $ \\
\verb|\myforalll|: $\myforalll $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using these techniques, you can customize your quantifiers in many ways, for instance:

```
\newcommand{\fa}{\kern.05em\ensuremath\forall\kern-.22em\rotatebox{69}{\rule{.73em}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\ex}{\kern.05em\ensuremath\exists\kern-.03em\rotatebox{90}{\rule{.68em}{.35pt}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the anser (+1). \myforall would be great if the additional line was a bit longer. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378: See the updated answer.

Comment: This was exactly what I was thinking about. Thus this was my second accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

You could make something along these lines by rotating `\mathbb{A}` and reflecting `\mathbb{E}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathbb{A}$} $\forall$
\reflectbox{$\mathbb{E}$} $\exists$
\end{document}
```

[image: symbols]

That way, you can experiment and pick the font you like best, e.g., mathrm:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version of `\exist` that has a double line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\eexists}{\ooalign{$\exists\,$\cr$\,\exists$}}
\begin{document}
Let's assume $\exists\mathcal{X}$ or $\eexists\mathcal{Y}$.
\end{document}
```

`\eexists` is an overlay of two `\exists` with some space inbetween.